# VB Program not working, should be simple

Tags: vb.net

This is a homework assignment, as far as I know I have everything I'm supposed to do. Yet it doesn't work for some reason. If I input "50000" for the Property Value, ".6" for the Assessment Percent, and ".7" for the Assessment Rate I should get "$210" for Property Tax, yet I keep getting only a zero, not sure what I missed. It's not due until Sunday, so if you only want to give me a hint that would also be appreciated. I've gone over the instructions and the code a few times and I'm still not seeing my mistake. I keep looking at "propertytaxLabel.Text = CDec(decTax)" like I messed up something there also.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub clearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
    valueTextBox.Clear()
    percentTextBox.Clear()
    rateTextBox.Clear()
    propertytaxLabel.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim result As DialogResult
    result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If result = DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub calculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculateButton.Click
    Try
        Dim decValue, decPercent, decRate, decTax As Decimal
        decValue = CDec(valueTextBox.Text)
        decPercent = CDec(percentTextBox.Text)
        decRate = CDec(rateTextBox.Text)

        propertytaxLabel.Text = CStr(decTax)

        If proceduresRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            TaxCalcProc(decValue, decPercent, decRate, decTax)
        Else
            decTax = TaxCalcFunc(decValue, decPercent, decRate)
        End If
        FormatCurrency(decTax)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Did you enter the data correctly?")
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub TaxCalcProc(ByVal propVal As Decimal, ByVal perc As Decimal, ByVal rate As Decimal, ByRef tax As Decimal)
    Dim AssessedValue As Decimal
    Try
        AssessedValue = propVal * perc
        tax = AssessedValue / 100 * rate
        If rate > 1 Or perc > 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("Tax Greater Than Value. Did you use the decimal point?")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Function TaxCalcFunc(ByVal propVal As Decimal, ByVal perc As Decimal, ByVal rate As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim tax As Decimal
    Dim AssessedValue As Decimal
    Try
        AssessedValue = propVal * perc
        tax = AssessedValue / 100 * rate
        If rate > 1 Or perc > 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("Tax Greater Than Value. Did you use the decimal point?")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return 0
    End Try
    Return Tax
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: turn on Option Strict, then set a breakpoint and debug it

Comment: In your codebehind right click on the line giving you an error and select insert breakpoint then run the program using the toolbar

Comment: Nothing is giving me an error, it's just not doing what it should. I think I have the wrong piece in the wrong spot, but I can't find it

Comment: Is proceduresRadioButton checked or unchecked?

Comment: I have "If proceduresRadioButton.Checked = True Then"

Comment: Try moving Return Tax to right before your Catch clause

Comment: Just for kicks, return -1 in your catch block instead of 0.  Are you still getting 0 or do you now get -1?

Comment: Please post the code to FormatCurrency

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking that was a user defined function.  sorry.

Comment: What you're going to need to do is put a breakpoint at this line:     AssessedValue = propVal * perc and while you are debugging, make sure your values are as expected.

Comment: This line propertytaxLabel.Text = CStr(decTax) should come after your call to FormatCurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out your decTax to your label after you are declaring it, but not after you are calculating it.

Try moving `propertytaxLabel.Text = CStr(decTax)` to after `FormatCurrency(decTax)` inside your button click event.

Comment: That was it, holy crap. Second time I made a mistake like that, right info in wrong place. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  We all make these mistakes, don't let anyone fool you.  I've been doing this for 7 years and I still make them from time to time.  Please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My VB is rusty, but you're not by any chance trying to convert "50,000" to a number, and it's failing because it has a comma in it? Most string -> int and string -> float conversions (in other languages) don't like commas.

Comment: Just checking, you had a comma in the description.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should research debugging and setting breakpoints with Visual Studio. It would make solving this very easy. Barring that, you can isolate and test your function with the following:

```
Private Sub calculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculateButton.Click
    Dim decTax As Decimal
    TaxCalcProc(50000D, 0.6D, 0.7D, decTax)
    Dim resultString = Format(decTax, "C")
    MessageBox.Show("decTax = " + resultString, "Test", MessageBoxButtons.Ok)
End Sub
```

Also, change:

```
AssessedValue / 100 * rate
```

to:

```
AssessedValue / 100D * rate
```

You probably have an unintentional case to `Int` because of the divide by 100. `100D` tells the compiler that you want a decimal number.